# Enable/disable features in Office 365 on a user or group basis?

Tags: office-365, feature

Is it in a way possible to enable/disable features in O365 (E1 Plan) on a per User/Group basis?

We'd like to enable the following features only for a specific group of users:

- Delve (Office Graph)
- Sites
- Yammer
- Video Portal
- One Drive for Business
- Office Groups

I could only find the option to disable it globally for a all users.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't understand the question... You mean you have list of user or all and you want change their license options (Plans)? For example, if you want to disable "Sites" you need to disable license option - "Sharepoint (Plan 1)" etc.

Example on PowerShell

*(ctreate variable for license options)*

```
$myO365SkuOption = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId <tenant>:ENTERPRISEPACK `
-DisabledPlans SHAREPOINTWAC
```

*(set this option to user)*

```
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName user1@tenant.onmicrosoft.com `
 -LicenseOptions $myO365SkuOption
```

Or you can do it from GUI Admin center (User list menu)